# Is there any way to build just changed code in msbuild

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iis, msbuild, development-environment

I have an scenario that I have to build my project and copy generated dll to another path.Because In our company every one builds his project and copy his dll to another path and IIS run all dll together as a single web application(we copy our dll by post build scripts).

But it takes me alot of time and for seeing every bit change I have to wait alot of time to build,copy,reset IIS(some time) and see my result.Is there any way to config Msbuild to build just part of my code that changed and I see my result in shorter time as like as debug mode in visual studio.In debug mode you change your code and msbuild can rebuild new changes and shows you just in time.

note : in development environment every one has a local IIS with compatible dll of others.

note : Because of some custom settings, no one can run his project in visual studio by run debug

I appreciate of any help

Comment: What project type are you hosting? Is that a mvc .net core app?

Comment: our projects are asp.net webform and every single project is class library but has asp user component in herself

Comment: In asp.net webform you can just swap your dll on the go without having to rebuild the project

Comment: we do this.but for every little changes we have to build our project and iis try to reload it again.this takes a lot of time.for example for ever change you have to wait about five minutes

Comment: I don't know how visual studio handle changes while is running in debug mode.I want some thing like this

Comment: How about you just deploy a debug version of an app? Like, pull the project from git into an iis app folder, dont even build it.

Comment: I didn't get your advice exactly.but if you mean why every sources are not in same place and build all, it's because of different team projects.every team project just deliver one dll that has their user controls.and one web project try to collect all dlls and show them in web.